# ObjectMapper - no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

Facing issue while making call to retrieve a json response and parse it.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false).configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);

mapper.convertValue(respDataString, GetListingListResponse.class);
```

where respDataString is

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "branch_reference": "148644",
    "listings": []
}
```

GetListingListResponse.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "status",
        "branch_reference",
        "listings"
})
public class GetListingListResponse implements Serializable
{

    @JsonProperty("status")
    private String status;
    @JsonProperty("branch_reference")
    private String branchReference;
    @JsonProperty("listings")
    private List<Listing> listings;

}
```

Listing.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "listing_etag",
        "listing_reference",
        "url"
})
public class Listing implements Serializable
{

    @JsonProperty("listing_etag")
    private String listingEtag;
    @JsonProperty("listing_reference")
    private String listingReference;
    @JsonProperty("url")
    private String url;

}
```

Exception

> (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"status":"OK","branch_reference":"148644","listings":[]}')
> at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1455)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1081)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:371)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:323)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1408)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:176)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:166)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:4229)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:4165)

I have no idea on it. Is there any problem ?

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear why you would be using the method `ObjectMapper.convertValue(Object fromValue, Class<T> toValueType)`. That method basically serializes the first argument to JSON, then deserializes it back into the type `toValueType`. [JavaDoc is here](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.14.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-).

What you probably want is `ObjectMapper.readValue(String content, Class<T> valueType)` which deserializes an input `String` of JSON into the specified type.

Comment: Because I would like to convert an JSON output string to an POJO object.

Comment: Like I said, `convertValue()` isn't the method for that. What you're describing is called _deserialization_, not "conversion," and `readValue()` is the way to go.